# Resource size categories (normal / large) - How do i avoid duplication

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a layout file present for specifically `layout-normal-land` normal landscape screens, for every other screen size and orientation I want to use the default `layout` folder -

But, screen sizes higher than normal will now use `normal-land` as the closest fit resource rather than falling back to default.

I could just add the resource into `layout-large-land` but this then means (since I want to use this same layout file for portrait screens of all sizes) I would have to make a duplicate copy of the layout file in `layout` as well.

Can someone tell me how to get around duplicating this file?

Comment: To avoid this duplication of the same file use Layout Aliases http://stackoverflow.com/a/11396186/1012284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping this isn't the best case scenario:

Using @PadmaKumar s comment I'm using [layout-alias](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters) to "override" the id used to load resource in `default` and `large-land` instances:

I have this structure instead:

```
layout/
    fragment_layout_default.xml
layout-normal-land/
    fragment_layout.xml
values/
    layout.xml
values-large-land/
    layout.xml
```

where as the contents of the layout.xml in `values` and `values-large-land` contain:

@layout/fragment_main_menu_default

This stops me from code duplications but still seems a bit... -ick-